# Is it possible to use jQuery into background-image of different div?

Tags: jquery, rollover

I want to fade in background-images on a different disjointed div...

http://www.bpanzullo.com/WebTech/index.html

Using id's from the leftnav class (either hover or click is OK) to show up in the #rightcol div using #rightcol background-image (using jQuery, but CSS is OK too).

```
<div id="leftcol">
   <div class="content">
    <ul class="leftav">
        <li class="leftnav" id="webhosting"><a href="#">Web Hosting<span class="greenSmall">Get more information</span></a></li>
        <li class="leftnav" id="cpanel"><a href="#">cPanel<span class="greenSmall">Get more information</span></a></li>
        <li class="leftnav" id="emailhosting"><a href="#">Email Hosting<span class="greenSmall">Get more information</span></a></li>
        <li class="leftnav" id="reseller"><a href="#">Reseller<span class="greenSmall">Get more information</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

//then have the background-images show up below inside the #rightcol div

```
<div id="rightcol"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone found the answer of why it wasn't working - I used the word language instead of type in the opening javascript declaration:

> script language="text/javascript"
>
> script type="text/javascript"

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#webhosting').click(function() { 
        $('#rightcol').css("background-image", "url(css3menu/webhosting.png)"); 
     }); 

    $('#cpanel').click(function() { 
        $('#rightcol').css("background-image", "url(css3menu/cpanel.png)"); 
     });
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

First copy the content

```
$("#rightcol").append($("#leftcol .content").html());
```

After that call the effect

Comment: I think I'm close with this:       <script language="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#emailhosting').click(function()
{
  $('#rightcol').css("background-image", "url(http://www.bpanzullo.com/WebTech/css3menu/emailhosting.png)");  
 });
});

</script>

Comment: Someone found the answer of why it wasn't working - I used the word language instead of type in the opening javascript declaration:
<script language="text/javascript">  

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
   
        $('#webhosting').click(function() { 
            $('#rightcol').css("background-image", "url(css3menu/webhosting.png)"); 
         }); 
           
        $('#cpanel').click(function() { 
            $('#rightcol').css("background-image", "url(css3menu/cpanel.png)"); 
         }); 

etc.

Comment: @BobPanzullo I think is best you remove this question and reformulate it with all code